# Update database with uploaded file using Django

Tags: mysql, django, forms

I am new to **Django**
I have a MySQL database - which I want to update using a *csv* file.  I intend to use the LOAD DATA command of MySQL 
How do I go about it?  - or is there a better way ?

How should I create the upload form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the csv module in Python to read the file and loop over the rows:

```
import csv

csv_file = open('path/to/file', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for column1, column2, column3 in reader:
    #do something with the data here
```

Hope that helps!

This section is a followup showing a sample view:

```
#NOT TESTED
import csv

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

form my_app.forms import MyForm
from my_app.models import MyModel

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
    else:
        form = MyForm(request.FILES, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            the_file = form.cleaned_data.get('the_file_field', None)
            if the_file:
                reader = csv.reader(the_file)
                for column1, column2, column3 in reader:
                    my_model = MyModel.objects.create(column1=column1, \
                    column2=column2, column3=column3)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Thanks,I think that might be quite helpful. If I do not wish to store the file uploaded - i.e how do I take the data from the file uploaded and bound to the form?
Also, I need the csv information to be inserted into a db. How to write view for that

Comment: You should be able to reference the uploaded file directly from the request.POST collection. (I haven't tested that with this method, but have used that on similar functions) I'll post another answer with a sample view.

Answer (score 0):

To do this using Django, you might be better off writing a view and a supporting model that would have a form to upload your file, then parse the file row by row for information to be inserted into your database.